# How do I select parents and children together in the outliner?

Tags: parent, outliner

So for example I have a model chair which includes the arms, piston (that type of chair), base etc. How do I select all parts including the parent item for duplicating the model? Shift+G only allows me to select the children but not parent. I'm fairly beginner with Blender.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hold CTRL while selecting the parent in the outliner, you should see every children of that object highlithed in orange as well, that tells you they are selected too.